AttributeError: partially initialized module 'threading' has no attribute 'RLock' (most likely due to a circular import)
Sorry to ask but I'm a newbie in Python and just doing a presonal project.
This is my folder structure
Main Folder
Inside Main folder I only have setup_log.txt and setup_tool.py. Other than that none.
Here's the code where I used the threading
import threading
class Spinner:
    def __init__(self, message="Processing"):
        self.spinner = itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\'])
        self.stop_running = threading.Event()
        self.message = message
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.init_spin)

    def init_spin(self):
        while not self.stop_running.is_set():
            sys.stdout.write(f'\r{self.message} {next(self.spinner)}')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + ' ' * len(self.message) + ' \r')  # Clear the line

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_running.set()
        self.thread.join()

Now the error

When I run python using 'python setup_tools.py' it returns this error
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Desktop\2024\asc_developer_V2\setup_tool.py", line 2, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 51, in <module>       
    import threading
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 232, in <module>
    _lock = threading.RLock()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'threading' has no attribute 'RLock' (most likely due to a circular import)**





Your code is working. MY output:
Supra |
Supra /
Supra -
Supra 
Supra |
Supra /
Supra -
Supra 
Supra |
Supra /
Supra -
Supra 
Supra |
Supra /
Supra -
Supra 
Supra |
Supra /
Supra -
Supra 
Supra |
Supra /
Supra -
Supra 
Supra |
Supra /
Supra -
Supra \

Can you please share your setup_tools.py code? Bcz the error is coming from that file.

Your code looks good.
You have a file named threading.py.
This file is causing the error.
Change the name of the file to something else and try again.
Note: Please refrain from naming your files with module names, keywords, etc.
